# How to get any y value for specified x in chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

[image: Example image]

This example is very skewed, but it shows my point well enough.  The blue line has a large gap (so a bunch of extrapolated data) for the first ~2 weeks of Nov.  I want to hover over point on the red line, and get the corresponding data for the blue line.  I've found `scale.getValueForPixel(value)` but that only gets data for the exact point in the scale.  I haven't been able to find a corresponding function for whatever the `line` is.

Is there any way for me to get the extrapolated data from any point on a line?

Answer (score -1):

A simple to way to get this done is binding the canvas for onClick event, and use the following code, also here is a working fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/Lzo5g01n/4/

```
document.getElementById("myChart").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var element = myChart.getElementAtEvent(e)[0];
  if (element) {
    alert(myChart.config.data.datasets[element._datasetIndex].data[element._index]);
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work in my case. You're going off of index which explicitly won't work for my chart pictured above.

Comment: Can you share the code of your chart, I will make it work.

Comment: This example shows my problem.  The pink and blue lines line up wit the same x/time value so would work traditionally, but the turquoise line has its own x/time values that don't match the other two lines.  https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/time/line.html  https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/scales/time/line.html